# Does "till Monday" include Monday?

Tags: dates, range-inclusion

My boss told me on Wednesday, "Please don't come to work til Monday."

So when does this means I have to go back to work? On Monday or Tuesday?

Comment: Go back to work on Monday. If he had meant Tuesday, he'd have said so, or he'd have said "Don't come to work until after Monday."

Answer (score 12):

She wants you to go to work on Monday. When talking about time, the word "till"  (or "until") usually doesn't include the endpoint. For example, "I don't have class until 5:00" implies that I have class at 5. Once it reaches 5, the statement "I don't have class" no longer applies. Similarly, once it reaches Monday, the statement "don't come back to work" no longer applies.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is (it could be yours or it couldn't), but I do not agree with this explanation, for the following reason. The example you give makes use of a point in the time (5 o'clock) that has no time extension, so it doesn't even make sense to distinguish between including 5:00 or not. A day of the week has got a length, so it's extremely important whether it is included or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you say "I *don't* have class till Monday", Monday will not be included.
But when you say "I have class till Tuesday," Tuesday is included.

Comment: So you are saying that the "object" of till is always included (and if there's a negation, also that "object" is negated).

Answer (score 0):

'Til is a contraction of the word "until". The word "until" is defined by [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en) via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=until) as:

> up to (the point in time or the event mentioned)

And gives the following example:

> The kidnappers have given us until October 11th to deliver the documents.

This means that "until" defines a terminal point to a range of time. In the example given in the question, the mandate, "Don't come in," applies through the week and stops applying on the stated day, Monday. You should go to work Monday.

Grammatically, "until" as used here is a preposition and has for its object "Monday". It effectively modifies the verb "come" (which is also modified by the adverb "don't").