# When the deadline is June 15, is June 15 included too?

Tags: dates

> You can send your application by June 15.
>
> The deadline for application is June 15.
>
> The application period ends on June 15.

Is the last day usually meant to be included in statements such as above? Can one apply on June 15?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Until - ambiguity](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138523/until-ambiguity)

Comment: Related: [Does "till Monday" include Monday](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68673/does-till-monday-include-monday).

Comment: @JamesK This question is not about "until" or "till".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is understood that a “deadline date” includes that date, through the close of business that date.

- when U. S. tax filings are due on April 15, any submission that is received by the post office on April 15 are honored.
- “offer expires December 31” indicates that responses received on that date (or purchases made on that date) will be honored.

In your examples, applications received **on** June 15 should be honored (during normal business hours).   Applications dropped in the mail elsewhere on June 15, and not received by June 15, likely wouldn’t be.

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is not what the words mean, but what the writer intended them to mean. If you want to know that you have to ask them to give a deadline in terms of a specific time and date. Even if they do mean that you can apply on June 15 they might not welcome an application at 11.59 pm on June 15.